# What is the difference between "docker run my_image" and "docker run -it my_image"

Tags: docker

When I containerize my image with `docker run my_image` and `docker run -it my_image`, both works same, but what is the difference ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

Comment: The difference is that your terminal is attached to the latter container. So if the program running asks for input, you can give it to the latter, but not the former. Ctrl-C also works in the latter to stop the program. Doesn't work in the former.

Comment: Just in case for the audience: the _both works same_ part is **not** correct due the behavior of the latter against the former

Answer (score 0):

The docker run command is used to start a new container from an image. The difference between docker run my_image and docker run -it my_image is in the way they interact with the container.

docker run my_image runs the container in the background, detached from the terminal. The container will continue to run in the background until it is stopped or exits.

docker run -it my_image runs the container in the foreground, attached to the terminal. The -it option allows you to interact with the container using the terminal. This is useful for running commands within the container and observing the output in real-time.

In summary, docker run my_image is used to run a container in the background without interaction, while docker run -it my_image is used to run a container in the foreground and interact with it using the terminal.

Comment: The first command does not run the container in the background